# Jquery Show/Hide multiple divs with transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to have a single button show and hide multiple divs. The problem I ran into and haven't been able to construct is a working script that has each div transition during the show/hide and once completed loop back thru the function.

div.bg-1, div.content-1, div.link-1 are visible on page load.

On button.btn click div.bg-1 fades to show div.bg-2, div.content-1 swipes left to show div.content-2 and div.link-1 has no transition but displays div.link-2.

On the next button.btn click div.bg-2 fades to show div.bg-3, div.content-2 swipes left to show div.content-3 and div.link-2 has no transition but displays div.link-3.

Once div.bg-3 is shown on button.btn click it would loop back thru to show div.bg-1

```
<div class="bg-1 current display"></div>
<div class="bg-2 current"></div>
<div class="bg-3 current"></div>

<div class="content-1 current display"></div>
<div class="content-2 current"></div>
<div class="content-3 current"></div>

<div class="link-1 current display"> <a href="/foo"></a> </div>
<div class="link-2 current"> <a href="/alpha"></a> </div>
<div class="link-3 current"> <a href="/beta"></a> </div>

<button class="btn"></button>
```

I was able to get the divs to show and hide with the script below. However I don't think this is the most efficient and effective way, especially to add the desired different transitions to each element and loop back thru the function.

```
    $(".btn").click(function () {
    if ($(".current").next(".display").length) {
       $(".current").removeClass("current").next(".display").addClass("current");     
    }    
});
```

Thank you all in advace! I really appreciate any input and help.

Comment: ID's have to be unique. First three div's have same `id's`

Comment: ahhh sorry they are classes in my file. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to chain your effect and you can use jquery ui effect http://jqueryui.com/effect/. For exemple if you use blind.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $("#div1").show('blind', 1000, function () {
        $("#div2").show('blind', 1000, function () {
            $("#div3").hide('blind', 1000);
        });

    });

    );     

}
```

In this example, the div1 will show, 1 second later the div2 will show and 1 second later the div3 will hide. You can chain what ever you want whit the effect you want.